# .Net form controls drop by one "line" after selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

Yes, I realize that's a bit of a vague title but I'm having a hard time stating the problem.  I have a .Net .aspx page that has a Master page, some Ajax, and an updatepanel.  My problem occurs on 2 different pages but in both cases I'm either selecting a radio button or a checkbox when the behavior occurs.  Immediately after selection the entire page moves down.  It does not scroll but instead it is like an extra 
 tag was inserted into the source.  I have done HTML source comparisons before and after this change and nothing is different.  I can only assume it is related to the updatepanel but I cannot determine where this may be happening.
I'd be happy to provide more information if you can direct me towards a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen in multiple browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this will do it and there is not enough detail here to be sure, but have you tried setting RenderMode to inline on the UpdatePanel? Maybe that will do the trick. Otherwise go take a look at Fiddler and see what is coming back from the server. Alternate recommendation (if none of the above work) is to just get your result in Json and change the markup yourself with jQuery or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

Incredible.  This was exactly the problem.  I've modified my code as follows and form stays in place after selection.  This was a simple case of selecting a radio button and having it auto-populate a dropdownlist.

```
[asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelValidation" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always" RenderMode="Inline"]
  [ContentTemplate]
      [asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"]
  [ContentTemplate]
[asp:UpdatePanel]
```

Thanks!